# Custom Bullet Images Floating Upwards When Oversized

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am attempting to use a star image for a custom bullet point on an `<li>` element. The issue that I am having is that the bottom of the image always sits on the bottom line of the font, so the image gets pushed up. Is there any way to fix this issue, or do I need to just ghetto it up and use a css background image?

```
ul.features-list {
    list-style-image: url('../assets/star-bullet.svg');
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.features-item {
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

[image]

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the current CSS and html you are using?

Comment: Can you share the code through jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: CSS background images are the most effective option, as you have much greater control over the image and positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You can use the Bullet image as a `Background-image` of `li`

Here is the working Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjJtC

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you dont want to use a `Background-image` you can try this method:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lwaky